# Carrierwave with MongoMapper returning nothing for non-uploaded users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

We have a user model that implements carrierwave for avatar uploading.

For users that have uploaded a photo, everything is fine. But for those that don't, when you call the #photo method, you get Nothing. Not nil, or blank string, absolutely nothing, so we can't index or do a number of things because of this. Seems like it should return nil.

Any thoughts on how to make that happen?

I'm using http://github.com/brandonhilkert/carrierwave-mongomapper

```
class User
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  ...
end

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog

  process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]

  version :normal do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end

irb(main):024:0> User.brandon.photo
=> 
irb(main):025:0> User.brandon.photo.class
=> PhotoUploader
irb(main):026:0> User.chris.photo
=> https://[redacted]/IMG_1160_2_bigger.jpg
irb(main):027:0> User.chris.photo.class
=> PhotoUploader
```

Comment: You can't just get nothing. Find out what you're actually being returned by trying ```User.brandon.photo.class```.

Comment: This is include above: irb(main):025:0> User.brandon.photo.class
=> PhotoUploader

Comment: It's like the to_s isn't generating anything on PhotoUploader class...

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/master/CarrierWave/Uploader/Proxy#blank%3F-instance_method), you can use `blank?`:

```
User.brandon.photo.blank? # should be true
User.chris.photo.blank? # should be false
```

Comment: I understand that's how you test if it's valid, but that's not what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement default_url in your Uploader  to a provider a default avatar

```
def default_url
  "/assets/avatars/{version_name}_default.png"
end
```

Then display your image as follows

```
image_tag User.brandon.photo_url(:normal)
```

Comment: The problem is that with tools like awesome_print, if you do: ap User.brandon, it'll iterate through all the properties and #photo is one of them. I know how to use the photo_url in the code to display the photo. Likewise, when elasticsearch goes to index, it tries to index the .photo property of the user and breaks, it's not actually looking for photo_url.